# Why are my questions considered "too localized"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, too-localized

I've noticed that a certain very-high-rep user consistently tries to close my questions as "too localized". The most recent example of this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851555/read-a-file-from-cache-but-without-polluting-the-cache-in-windows), and the other example I remember is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285585/rtldospathnametontpathname-u-on-c-returns-invalid-path) (but the comments are no longer all there anymore). There have been more but these are the only two I remember right now.

Now there's something I don't understand:

*What exactly* is it about these that's "too localized"?

Or rather: **Is** there anything that's too localized about them in the first place? (i.e. was the reason appropriate? Why/why not?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What questions should be closed with reason "too localized"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized)

Comment: @Mark: Not really, it's not a dup -- I'm asking about a specific incident here, and the duplicates don't really answer my question because they ran counter to what I observed.

Comment: @Popular Demand: I'd never noticed that tag until now, thanks for putting it! :)

Comment: Have you somehow upset the 'certain very-high-rep user?' I can't see any validity for the flag on either question. It might be because you're in a relatively specialised problem domain, but SO is supposed to include specialised problems - indeed, these are the ones least likely to be answered elsewhere by google.

Comment: @Phil: Hm... I guess the answer is "possibly"? On the one hand, there indeed *was* an incident a few months ago that upset *both* of us, but I don't see why it should be continuing until now... if anything, that incident itself was *caused* in a similar way (although for a completely different reason), so I don't think it explains what's happening. :( In case it is, though, where/how would be the best place/means of discussing it? Meta definitely isn't appropriate for it, so is there a better option?

Comment: @Mehrdad maybe chat?

Comment: @Earlz: Hm okay... haven't used the SO chat feature before but I guess now's the time to use it, haha. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the title to make it less misleading. Maybe it will stop others from voting to close as duplicate.

Comment: @alex: Ah ok good idea, thanks!

Comment: When you say that "but the comments are no longer all there anymore", does that imply that there was some *explanation* given in the comments, as to why that particular user voted to close as "too localized"?

Comment: @Cody: Kinda, not really. Well the thing is I'm not sure how to put it without also offending that person, so I'm being a bit vague on purpose... but since you asked, the comments were pretty much along the lines of "Windows was made to prevent stupid things from being done, if you really want this feature, go make your own OS, you might succeed; you don't need our advice, Linus never did". The user posted a copy of his quote down here too, but it was voted down and deleted so only 10K+ MSO users can probably see the post here.

Comment: @Mehrdad, you're welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think someone has a vendetta against you. I'm not seeing anything too localized about your two questions. Too Localized is commonly used as a secondary close reason for "plz post teh codez"(with Not a real question, being the primary). So some if your questions commonly come off that way, then the closer may be justified. But I personally see no problem with either of your questions.

Comment: +1 Interesting observation, that's quite possible although I don't think it *should* be, if I'm remembering the correct situation... I'll try to figure out what's going on then. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Its "too localized" to someone who doesn't care about WinAPI at all.

However I think this demonstrates that the "Too Localized" close reason doesn't have use/real questions to apply it to.

Comment: Too Localized is useful. For instance, gimme teh codez questions and questions like "What jobs are available in Rural Montana" or something. If it contributes nothing to the community as a whole(but instead benefits the author and maybe one or two other people), then it probably is too localized