# Proposal for new close reason: "not enough issue-focused"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I'm very active in the [Backbone tag stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/backbone.js) and I'm constantly seeing questions with a lot of lines of code exposes to try to add information about the issue to solve.

This is very good but for the fact that a lot of times **the exposed code contains most lines related to *personal business logic* than related to the *issue logic* itself**.

I think people should work a step forward and re-write their code to create a very simplified version of it very issue-focused, removing any line that is not relevant for the question and finding the minimal version of the code that reproduces the issue.

People are used to just copy their code and paste into the question without any abstraction work.

- Creating more abstract, personal business logic agnostic questions will produce more reusable answers and, at the same time, avoiding duplication.
- Creating more issue-focused questions will simplify the work of the people answering.

**I don't think this *close reason* fits into the *too localized* option** due the question actually *"is likely to help any future visitors"* the problem is that has to be redefined to focus in the issue in a more abstract way.

### Updated

**I don't think this *close reason* fits into the *not a real question* option** because it is not *ambiguous* due is too concrete, is not *vague* due is too much descriptive, is not *incomplete* due there is too much information (even non-relevant one), is not *overly broad* due is should be even more abstract, is not *rhetorical* because is not any kind of philosophical speech... Finally **it is a real question** it is just the person making it should describe it in a more issue-focused way, removing any non-relevant information.

### Updated

Maybe could be just enough not adding a new close reason but **adding a new *it is not a real question* definition**, like for example: *"or you have to work in expose your question more issue-focused removing any non-relevant information that doesn't offer more than noise"*

Comment: Would that not simply fall under "overly broad" of the "not a real question" description?

Comment: "Not a real question" is your friend - `This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.`

Comment: @Bart, Pekka Well, it is not _ambiguous_ due is too concrete, is not _vague_ due is too much descriptive, is not _incomplete_ due there is too much information (even non-relevant one), is not _overly broad_ due is should be even more abstract, is not _rhetorical_ because is not any kind of philosophical speech... Finally **it is a real question** it is just the person making it should describe it in a more issue-focused way, removing any non-relevant information.

Comment: If it should be more abstract, it's overly broad, isn't it? You want to OP to narrow it down. Make it smaller...

Comment: @Bart, yes _"Make it smaller"_ is what I want but don't think the expression _"overly broad"_ is fitting in this. I understand _overly broad_ like if for example I ask _"how to build a Backbone App?"_. Anyhow maybe could be just enough not adding a new _close reason_ but **adding a new _it is not a real question_ definition**, like for example: _"or you have to work in expose your question more issue-focused removing any non-relevant information that doesn't offer more than noise"_

Comment: @muistooshort maybe you can expose your opinion about this proposition, I'm sure you have reflected about this already.

Comment: My answer [to this request for another close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142885/153020) could fit here too.

Comment: @Flexo, indeed, I think the _sub-reasons_ approach is a better solution to achieve my proposition, check my last update.

Comment: I have no idea what your close reason is supposed to mean. By the way, note that close reasons make sense on all Stack Exchange sites. If you think you've found a close reason that's specific to one tag on one site, think again.

Answer (score 5):

We don't need more close reasons, or sub-reasons for the close reasons.  The existing list of close reasons already creates enough cognitive dissonance; voting to close should be as frictionless as possible.

Having a laundry list of close reasons would have a chilling effect on closing questions.  Imagine if you had to pick a specific close reason from the ones described in What Stack Overflow is Not.  You'd never close anything; it would be too much trouble.

It would be better if there were a meta post for each close reason, explaining the sub-reasons why a question is closed.

Comment: What would a meta post for each reason achieve? **If it is not clear to a new user how the close reason applies to the question, leave a comment that is tailored to the question.**

Comment: A meta post provides an authoritative reference.