# Close reason to use for a "Gimme the Codez" question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible new close reason: “Overt request for code”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142870/possible-new-close-reason-overt-request-for-code)

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110504/android-exporting-to-csv-and-implementing-pseudocode) which is a blatant (to  my eyes anyway) "gimme teh codez" question.  I'm going to vote to close but can't decide which is the appropriate reason... I can see arguments for all of them excpet for the Exact Duplicate.

Is there a standard reason to use when voting to close for these types of questions?

**EDIT**

And after I added a comment asking if he expected us to write his code for him, he deleted the above referenced question.  :)

Anyway, my question here still stands, regardless of an example to point to.  What is the most appropriate close vote reason to use?

Comment: `Not Constructive`, `Not a real question`, `Too localized` pick your choice. I'm sure this is a duplicate, by the way.

Comment: If it is a duplicate, then the first one is not named well.  I actually searched before I posted.  (I like to be thorough and not post a dupe ya see, it wastes my time and yours).  :p

Comment: @Bart, your search-fu is better than mine.  Thanks for the link.  Not a dupe, but if I'd found that first I probably would not have posted my question, as CasperOne pretty clearly states (and given his diamond mod status I'd give his opinion some weight) in the comments the preference to use NARQ as the reason.

Comment: Yeah, it's not dupe-dupe, but all the info there can basically be used to answer your question as well.

Comment: That's odd... voting to close my own question.  I'd just delete it, but I'd rather leave it as a signpost for people searching on "gimme the codez" to point to the other answer.  And hopefully it won't throw me into a question ban.  Shouldn't, as I believe it will be my first closed question.  Guess we'll find out.

Comment: I fully expect you to be hauled off by various moderators only to end up in duplicate-dungeon while being forced to scoop the poop of reject-unicorns the result of experimental.....I think I'll stop here...

Comment: @Barak thats part of the reason for not deleting dupes, it helps with the googling.