# 'Pure code asking question' - How should these be flagged?

Tags: support, flags

I would like to know what exactly should be picked up from the flagging options when we see a pure code-request question, or a question that describe a coding problem but doesn't provide a sample code/error.

I guess a new option of pure-code requested should be added to the list in the 2nd Flagging option 'This does not belong here'.

I know there are questions that are on topic and does not always need a code sample. But my concern is with the pure input/output kind of questions.

What do you say?

Comment: I'd probably flag as Not A Real Question.

Comment: NARQ (with a bit of a wait for any "what've you tried, plz show teh codez" comments to take effect).

Comment: There are many questions that are simple enough that a code sample isn't needed.

Comment: @Lance Yes, I know. My concern is regarding a pure code request for a specific input/output kind of questions.

Comment: Related feature-request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142870/possible-new-close-reason-overt-request-for-code

Comment: @bfavretto Thanks for the link. Just a thought - the description of it should say 'It's so overt that it is covert' :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple options, including not flagging at all. I personally wouldn't flag or vote to close "a question that describe a coding problem but doesn't provide a sample code/error" just because there is no sample code. If the problem is well described, it might be enough. But that can only be decided on a case-by-case basis.

As for pure code-requests, here is what I do:

- VTC as "too localized" or "not a real question" if the request is like "I need code that does *X*" (I use "too localized" when *X* is something very specific).
- VTC as "not constructive" if the question is asking for libraries, plugins etc.

Comment: Note that if what they're asking for is something that's likely to be useful for other people "too localized" doesn't apply.  Many of those questions should just be downvoted, not closed.

Comment: But not if it's a *plz gimme teh codez* question, right? Those, I vote to close, and even vote to delete.

Comment: No.  If it's clear what they want, and it's potentially useful to people other than them, then it doesn't meet any of the criteria for being closed (unless it's a dup).  Being lazy and not putting time into solving your own problem makes it low quality, but not close worthy.  They should just be downvoted.