# Add link to explanation what is real question to not make user confused

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, not-a-real-question

Please add an explanation in section with comment what is real question to not make user confused with valid or invalid moderation.

It will be nice to see on this page that this question was closed because it does not fulfill the definition so we can judge if reason was right or not.

---

Simple example - some people close a question because they do not know the answer and mark it as not a question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642282/how-to-write-mediawiki-plugin-which-will-add-some-html-just-after-body-what

Support sends me link when I asked what is real question since not understand it?
[What is considered a "real question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question)

See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157444/could-you-explain-what-closed-as-not-real-question-means

Current [link is to faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

Whatever you should also fix moderation since "real question" become "not real" according definiction from both documents.

Comment: What is "not real" in feature request explain if you are constructive?

Comment: I think you're slightly confused. The users who closed your question were not moderators. They were ordinary users like yourself. Equally the user who posted a link to [What is a Real Question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question) is not support. They are an ordinary user like yourself.

Comment: I'm guessing that @Asad is saying that it's unclear exactly where you'd like this link to be? In the same place as the link to the FAQ on the banner explaining why a question was closed? There is, I think, a kernal of a good idea here but I'm having trouble deciphering what you're asking for. Are you able to explain?

Comment: @Ben tell me how to contact with moderators if you know or it possible since it looks that many people close question if can not answer to it or for fun - it makes content poor and my experience too :)

Comment: @Asad where is detailed post _There's a very detailed post on this in the question you linked to._ ???

Comment: @Chameleon: That's a very bold claim and you better can now give examples of that.

Comment: You are in the right place. Your question was closed as part of community moderation. Not for fun, but because it's not a good question. You can flag for moderator attention and have them evaluate it, but at this point that's useless since I'm pretty sure they would agree with the closure.

Comment: Moderators are constantly on meta.stackoverflow. One will, I'm sure, be along shortly and add something if they feel like anything is missing to your previous question. As to why people close questions this has been discussed extensively and you have a question related to your own closed question. Please don't use a feature request to discuss specific questions as it just really confuses matters.

Comment: I asked about feature to show explanation why question is close instead "magic slag" like "not real question" which lead all user to ask such question or to judge it if close since moderation is good or bad. - example is given to learn why it is not important.

Comment: I think that I have some blidness it explains directly that it is invalid moderation and it is bellow question _It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ._.

Comment: @Chameleon The question was not closed by moderators, it was closed by other users who voted for it to be closed. Additionally, that passage you are quoting is explaining why the question is not a good fit for SO, it is not claiming the reason for closing your question was invalid.

Comment: @Asad You criticism is not constructive - tell me what specific reason classify this question as good or bad - not talk in general to be specific?

Comment: @Chameleon I'm not saying your question was good or bad, nor am I criticizing you. All I'm saying is that there was no moderation involved: a bunch of users like you or I decided the question should be closed, so that's what happened.

Comment: @Asad Now your explanation are very clear and constructive thanks - it is very good to avoid general talks since lead to "nothing". For me invalid moderation is also censorship of bunch of users since it lead to poor content if users close questions since can not answer t them (it has two simple sentence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There already is a link in the text that explains why your question was closed.

> It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, [see the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close).

That links to the [Why are some questions closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) section of the FAQ, which contains a further link to [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: But it doesn't link to [What is a Real Question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145677) which I guess is his point.

Comment: @Pekka Yes there is no link or better there is no explanation on page what is metaphor "real question" it could be 3 point in comment to judge if it good moderation or bad. For example it could look like this: it is "not real question" because: 1. xxx, 2. xxx, 3. xxx, ...

Comment: @Chameleon That's kind of the point of the text "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Comment: @Pekka We would have to have equivalent questions for all close reasons before we could start linking to those instead of the FAQ.

Comment: @Bill true, but arguably, that doesn't mean much, especially not to a ESL speaker who's on the site for the first time. The Meta FAQ entry seems like a better resource.

Comment: @Asad not necessarily IMO. "Not a real question" and "not constructive" seem to be those items that are hardest to grasp

Comment: I believe to have read that some clarification of closure reasons is being undertaken anyway? So perhaps it's worth it to wait that out and see if that changes things.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Blidness - my fault please close this feature request and reopen this question since it closed with invalid reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13642282/how-to-write-mediawiki-plugin-which-will-add-some-html-just-after-body-what - iti is very specific - **please point hook!** _I want to put some banner/header at top of Mediawiki page and want to write some plugin doing such thing. Could you help with this I am not know what hook or specific method should be used to modify Mediawiki page?_ :)