# Should we add "What is real question" link to the close tab of FAQ?

Tags: discussion, questions

Questions can be closed as "Not a Real Question."

But on the close tab of [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close), there is no link to point to [What is considered a "real question"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question)

It is already on [FAQ index](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) but wouldn't be great writing also to the close tab of FAQ especially for new users?

Comment: Yes please. Meta is an unnavigable ocean for newbies.

Comment: @Pekka웃: If Meta is an ocean...who gets to be the pirate?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby WE ARRRR