# Are questions about software update schedules/availability on-topic?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I'm one of the top contributers in the [dynamics-crm-2011](/questions/tagged/dynamics-crm-2011) tag. It's a small tag, and I often see questions like a question I saw today ([Not seeing any Rollup 12 download file? (CRM 2011 On-Premise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317064/not-seeing-any-rollup-12-download-file-crm-2011-on-premise)), in which the questionner asks about the scheduling and the availability of the next update for the Dynamics CRM platform.

I downvoted this question and voted to close as off-topic. I thought the question isn't directly about software development but rather about the logistics of a software platform update, but since there are few other regular contributors to this tag that have enough reputation to vote to close, I'm not sure whether no one else has voted to close this question simply due to lack of exposure, or whether it's in fact because the question *is* on-topic.

Is it generally the consensus of the community that such questions are valid, or is it more likely the case that enough like-minded voters haven't seen this question?

Comment: Too localized... Closed.  More info [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/87415).

Comment: I would say this is primarily too localized. Perhaps of interest now, but no longer in a month or so.

Comment: Cool. @RobertHarvey: for a moment I thought you were talking about this question! :-) Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add an answer to this question, I believe that the consensus is that such questions are too localized, due to the timeframe inherent in the question. See the [comments on the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163757/are-questions-about-software-update-schedules-availability-on-topic#comment476611_163757) for more detail.

Comment: Did you really need to link the answer to the question? I clicked on the link three times before I figured out what the hell was going on.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Haha, if anyone upvotes [your comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163757/are-questions-about-software-update-schedules-availability-on-topic/164026#comment477598_164026), I'll remove it.